# Is it possible to get modified parameter value after passing base class function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to have **Child Damage to print 5 instead of 10?**
or do i have to use the `ref` keyword here?

Thanks.

This is my base class

```
public class DemoInheritance : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            float damage = 10;
            OnTakeDamage(damage);
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnTakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        Debug.Log("Base Damage: " + damage);
        damage -= 5;
        Debug.Log("New Damage: " + damage);
    }
}
```

My inherited class

```
public class DemoInheritanceChild : DemoInheritance
{
    public override void OnTakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        base.OnTakeDamage(damage);
        Debug.Log("Child Damage: " + damage);
    }
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't compile: ''DemoInheritanceChild.OnTakeDamage(ref float)': no suitable method found to override'. You need to specify the 'ref' keyword in DemoInheritance as well if you want it used in DemoInheritanceChild's override.

Comment: @AlexanderPope sorry there was a typo just now. edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options to get the modified data across.  You *could* have the function return the results of the manipulated variable, or you *could* just use the `ref` keyword, but I would argue that a [`public virtual` method is an anti-pattern](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) and advise you avoid that entirely.

Instead I'd suggest separating the public exposure of the class's methods from the classes ability to override its behavior:

```
public class DemoInheritance : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            float damage = 10;
            OnTakeDamage(damage);
        }
    }

    public void OnTakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        Debug.Log("Base Damage: " + damage);
        damage -= 5;
        Debug.Log("New Damage: " + damage);

        PostDamageResolved(damage);
    }

    protected virtual void PostDamageResolved(float postResolutionDamage);
}

public class DemoInheritanceChild : DemoInheritance
{
    protected override void PostDamageResolved(float postResolutionDamage)
    {
        Debug.Log("Child Damage: " + postResolutionDamage);
    }
}
```

Further, if `OnTakeDamage` is only ever called buy `Update()` in the base class, it should not be `public`:

```
public class DemoInheritance : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            float damage = 10;
            OnTakeDamage(damage);
        }
    }

    private void OnTakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        Debug.Log("Base Damage: " + damage);
        damage -= 5;
        Debug.Log("New Damage: " + damage);
        PostDamageResolved(damage);
    }

    protected virtual void PostDamageResolved(float postResolutionDamage);
}

public class DemoInheritanceChild : DemoInheritance
{
    protected override void PostDamageResolved(float postResolutionDamage)
    {
        Debug.Log("Child Damage: " + postResolutionDamage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

u not need to use ref as keyword,it will be worked like this

```
public class DemoInheritanceChild : DemoInheritance
{
    public override void OnTakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        base.OnTakeDamage(damage);
        Debug.Log("Child Damage: " + damage);
    }
}
```

Comment: if u want use ref , u need to use it all in your funcs

Comment: "if u want use ref , u need to use it all in your funcs" - what exactly do you mean?